# Why is RMSEA typically reported with a 90% confidence interval, and not 95%?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Kline (2016) writes that

> [RMSEA] is usually reported in computer output with the 90% confidence
>   interval $[\hat{\epsilon}_{L},\hat{\epsilon}_{U}]$ where
>   $\hat{\epsilon}_{L}$ is the lower-bound estimate of $\epsilon$, the
>   parameter estimated by $\hat{\epsilon}$, and $\hat{\epsilon}_{U}$ is
>   the upper-bound estimate. If $\hat{\epsilon} = 0$, then
>   $\hat{\epsilon}_{L}$ and the whole interval is a one-sided confidence
>   interval where $\hat{\epsilon}_{U} > \hat{\epsilon}$. This explains
>   why the confidence level is 90% instead of the more typical 95%, the
>   conventional level for two-sided confidence intervals.

I am having trouble following Kline's logic here. I understand that a RMSEA below 0 is nonsensical, but how does that argue in favor of a 90% CI?

Kline, R. B. (2016). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling. Guilford publications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curran et al. (2003) write that:

> It is common to report 90 percent confidence intervals for the RMSEA,
>   primarily because of the resulting direct link to hypothesis testing
>   based on the model test statistic.

Three hypothesis tests sometimes reported in the SEM literature are.

The test of exact fit, $H_{0}: \epsilon = 0$
and
The test of close fit, $H_{0}: \epsilon \leq .05$
and
The test of not-close fit, $H_{0}: \epsilon \geq .05$

Thus the ultimate rationale for using a 90% CI is that if you do that you can infer the results of those hypothesis tests from the CI. The relationship is illustrated in a table in MacCullum et al. (1996) p. 137.

[image]

Curran, P. J., Bollen, K. A., Chen, F., Paxton, P., & Kirby, J. B. (2003). Finite sampling properties of the point estimates and confidence intervals of the RMSEA. Sociological Methods & Research, 32, 208-252.

MacCallum, R. C., Browne, M. W., & Sugawara, H. M. (1996). Power analysis and determination of sample size for covariance structure modeling. Psychological methods, 1, 130.